# Paystack Gateway: Format is Authorization Bearer [secret key]

Tags: omnipay

I am using league/omnipay from [this repo](https://github.com/PaystackHQ/omnipay-paystack)

However, I always get this error as the PurchaseRequest Response

**{"status":0,"message":"Paystack Gateway: Paystack Gateway: Format is Authorization Bearer [secret key]"}**

What am I missing

Comment: Your information is not well stated. You're sending a wrong request

Answer (score 2):

Just add Bearer at this point in your code

"Authorization: Bearer sk_live_*************",

That's all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly [Follow this](https://github.com/yabacon/paystack-php) to make paystack payment with php. Make sure you're using your **paystack test key as the secret key**